# How to use Mocap_pose_estimate for sending Optitrach mocap pose data to fcu

Tags: ros, mavros, mocap-optitrack, optitrack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wish to send Optitrack mocap pose data (using vrpn_client_ros) to Pixhawk FCU through mavros_extras - mocap_pose_estimate plugin. However I do not see an executable made for mocap_pose_estimate plugin. So how do I use it ?

How to use that mocap_pose_estimate? Do I need to add executables for that in the CMakeLists.txt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238578/how-to-use-mocap_pose_estimate-for-sending-optitrach-mocap-pose-data-to-fcu/) by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2016-06-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is a plugin so you have to load into mavros node using a yaml as done [here](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/launch/px4_pluginlists.yaml).

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-07-01**:
Thanks for the reply @tonybaltovski. But I dont get it completely. I added mocap_pose_estimate in the px4flow_pluiglists.yaml file and launched the px4flow.launch. I do not think that is the right way.
Can you please explain in detail on how to use the mocap_pose_estimate pluigin?

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-07-01**:
I edited apm_pluiginlists.yaml file. I moved mocap_pose_estimate from blacklist list to whitelist. As a result of that now on running mavros I can see "Pluigin mocap_pose_estimate" loaded and initialized. However I dont yet get it. What is the next step?
Plugin needs to subscribe to pose and tf.How

**Comment by [stefrob](https://answers.ros.org/users/28035/stefrob/) on 2016-09-21**:
I am facing the same problem. Did u find a way to make it working?

**Comment by [mario1577](https://answers.ros.org/users/30158/mario1577/) on 2017-05-22**:
Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to publish the pose to the "/mavros/mocap/pose" topic.

Either write your own code to do it or use an existing ROS node.

As an example, let's use the "mocap_optitrack" package.

Edit mocap.yaml to publish the pose to "/mavros/mocap/pose" by modifying the following lines:

```
rigid_bodies:
    '1':
        pose: /mavros/mocap/pose
```

You can leave the rest as default.

Run mavros ( roslaunch mavros px4.launch ) and mocap_optitrack ( roslaunch mocap_optitrack mocap.launch ), and your FCU should receive mocap data.

You might need to increase the baud-rate of the connection between your PC and the Pixhawk in order to get this to work.

---

Originally posted by [JBannwarth](https://answers.ros.org/users/28139/jbannwarth/) with karma: 11 on 2016-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JustFineD](https://answers.ros.org/users/32602/justfined/) on 2017-11-12**:
HI @JBannwarth,
Using ArduCopter 3.5 -
I published mavros/mocap/pose topic - My FC change to GPS-3d fix and also receive the eph/epv/sats but it show me that the copter is in (0,0) global location. No matter how I change the (x,y,z) in the mocap topic, the copter doesn't move. what's wrong?